# why data retreival code for a WebPart is written in PreRender method

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, prerender

While writing code for connecting two webparts, i noticed that when i try to retrieve the data from Provider WebPart in CreateChildControl method, the connection object is shown as NULL. However, when i write the code in PreRender method , everything is working fine.
 **Is there any specific reason to write the retrieval code in PreRender method only??**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Introducing ASP.NET Web Part Connections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188696.aspx)

> (...) the ASP.NET team recommends that consumer Web Parts should
>   not use methods or properties on the provider interface until the
>   PreRender phase. Specifically, they should not use methods or
>   properties on the provider interface in the 
>   method itself. The reason is that connections may have dependencies on
>   each other. You may have a ProviderWebPart, connected to a
>   ProviderConsumerWebPart, connected to a ConsumerWebPart. The
>   ConsumerWebPart cannot query the provider interface until both
>   connections have been established, and the order in which the
>   connections are established is up to the Framework.

[SharePoint Web Part Event Flow in detail](http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/SharePoint-Web-Part-Event-Flow-in-detail.aspx)

[image: SharePoint Web Part - Event Flow chart]